# How can I connect to database using playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright

How to connect to a database using playwright? Is there any inbuilt feature in playwright or any external library that is compatible with playwright?

Comment: This depends in which language you are using Playwright. It seems like you are using TypeScript, so you can use any Node.js/NPM library, there are no limitations since its running in Node.js.